# 「なのだなと理解する」- what does the second な mean?

Tags: meaning, particle-な

For context: Person A brings up something about a club they are in, to which person B wonders whether it is a problem for person A. A third person (female, usually speaks formally) then chimes in, referring to person A:

> [A]も一員なのだなと理解しました

I think the first part is a sentence ending in 「なのです」, with 「です」 becoming 「だ」 for 「と臨海する」, but I can't figure out what the 「な」 between these two parts means. Without it, I would loosely interpret the sentence as something like

> [A] would not be a member of the club if it was a problem

But I am not sure whether the 「な」 carries some extra meaning I am unaware of. Is it something like a prohibitive form? Is it a variant of 「ね」? Or am I parsing the sentence wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here it is important to note the function of another particle 「と」in the sentence. As [goo辞書](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8/#jn-154670) explains:

> （文や句を**そのまま**受けて）動作・作用・状態の内容を表す。引用の「と」。

「そのまま」tells us when「と」is present you can leave the quotation as is, with all the particles that shape the way something is said. With this explained, let's look at your sentence.

> ([A]も一員なのだな)と理解しました

It now should be clear that the「な」is a sentence ending particle used to help express a personal feeling or to seek the listeners’ confirmation and/or to soften the imperative tone. And you are right that it functions similarly to「ね」. For example:

> この文章は大丈夫だな